# Get reference to root element of component in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I know I can get a reference to a DOM element by using `bind:this`:

```js
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let root;

  onMount(() => {
    // root is div
  });
</script>

<div bind:this="{root}">
  content
</div>
```

How can I get a reference to the DOM node of a root element of a component?

```js
Wrapper.svelte:
<div class="root">
  <slot />
</div>

App.svelte:
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let root;

  onMount(() => {
    // root is not div :(
  });
</script>

<Wrapper bind:this="{root}">
  content
</Wrapper>
```

Answer (score 10):

Svelte doesn't enforce a root component.

```
<p>I am valid component.</p>
<p>With multiple roots.<p>
```

```
<script>
  console.log('No root is valid too')
</script>
```

So there's not shortcut syntax to grab the root element, you need to manually "proxy" the element you want to expose:

`Wrapper.svelte`

```
<script>
  export let root
</script>

<div bind:this={root}>...</div>
```

`App.svelte`

```
<script>
  import Wrapper from './Wrapper.svelte'
  let el
</script>

<Wrapper bind:root={el} />
```

With a little exotic JS syntax, you can also replicate the `bind:this` syntax if you please:

`Wrapper.svelte`

```
<script>
  let root
  export { root as this }
</script>

<div bind:this={root} />
```

`App.svelte`

```
<script>
  import Wrapper from './Wrapper.svelte'
  let root
</script>

<Wrapper bind:this={root} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the DOM using the browsers devtools I recognized that a Svelte-Component created with `npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte-project` renders inside its `<main></main>` tag.

This means, in your case:

```
let element = document.querySelector('div.root')
```

should do the job.
Otherwise you can put a `<main></main>` tag surround your components html and request for `document.querySelector('main')`. This can be used with any css-selector.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't rely on what you suggest.
I am looking for a way to get the root without assuming anything about the current implementation or the page structure.

Comment: I totally agree that this "solution" is not a good paractice. @rixo solution fits best.